# Visual Studio 2008 and Office 2003

Tags: visual-studio-2008, vsto, office-2003

I have been interested in using the VSTO but I am running Visual Studio 2008 and I have Office 2003. I know it is possible to use VSTO 2005 SE for Office 2003 but I can't find any information on programming Office 2003 with VS2008. Is this possible? If so how do I do it?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to program Office 2003 with VS2008.  If i remember correctly, when you install VSTO, you will find you have two new project types - one for office 2003 and one for office 2007.

One thing to note is that upgrading visual studio from 2005 to 2008 will automatically upgrade your VSTO projects to Office 2007.  To get around this, see this article:

- [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150920051945/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2008/05/23/vs-2008-makes-me-upgrade-my-office-2003-add-in-but-i-don-t-want-to-anthony-crider.aspx)

Comment: One more thing - It's been a while since I did this, but I remember developing for both 2003 and 2007 at once was a bit fiddly - that was using VS2008.

Comment: Also, I think you need at least the Professional edition of Visual Studio